# How do I unlock scenes?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Are scenes only unlocked from bitizens with a "?", or any bitizen may trigger them?

Because I'm at level 25, and I don't remember the bitizen that triggered my only scene.

Comment: If you want to know who unlocks what, see also this other question:
http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/143685/66181

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 1.1.1932, there are 26 cutscenes.  Scenes are triggered by dropping off unique characters with the '?' in the elevator to a specific floor [as also mentioned in an answer per [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139180/why-does-the-bitzen-in-my-elevator-have-a-on-it)].

> A prime example is delivering the sticky buns Leia to the interrogation floor.

You can view your cutscenes anytime by going to your album and selecting the cutscenes tab.

[image: cutscene]

Answer (score 6):

- IG-88 or Chewie on HoloChess;
- IG-88, Gand, or Boba Fett (or any bounty hunter) for Bounty Hunters;
- Luke, Han, Leia, or Chewie on Detention Level;
- Luke or Leia (normal) on extending Bridge;
- Gungan on Mos Espa Cafe;
- Boba Fett or Han on Cloud City Spa;
- Obi Wan on Tractor Beam;
- Leia (normal) or Interrogation Droid on Interrogation;
- Imperial Gunner on Superlaser Tunnel;
- Luke, Han, Chewie, or Leia (normal) on Trash Compactor;
- Ewok on Imperial Museum (this one is hilarious, Yub Nub);
- Gungan or Pit Droid on Watto's Wares;
- Obi-Wan on Blast Doors;
- Chadra-Fan on Holonet Cineplex;
- Han or Greedo on Cantina;
- Luke (Hoth) on Scoop of Hoth;
- Luke or Obi Wan on Training Remotes;
- Luke on Tatooine Apts;
- Leia on Droid Lab;
- R5-D4 on Droid Store;
  -Mon Calamari  on Mon Cala Aquarium;

And I'm not sure about these, but I'm predicting:

- Yoda or Luke on Dagobah Apts;
- Vader on Vader Meditation;
- Imperial officer or Vader on Imperial Meeting Room;

Comment: Please avoid speculating in answers.

Comment: Admiral Ackbar does *not* unlock the scene for the Mon Cala Aquarium - just confirmed that on my playthrough.

Answer (score 2):

It's only the '?' bitizens.

You need to take them to the right level, but they need to be able to actually get off there. So if the level is above ground (i.e., not the Imperial levels) you are only able to take them there if they ask to be taken there, but the Imperial levels will accept any bitizen that stops at their level, so those scenes are easier to unlock.

In the Imperial Levels: Try New Hope Luke in the Detention Level, and ALSO New Hope Luke on the Extending Bridge.

Answer (score 1):

IG-88 and the holochess level unlock another scene, too.

Answer (score 1):

For Imperial Museum, it has to specifically be Wicket (ewok with red hood and appears with a ?), not just ANY Ewok. I have never had a Stormtrooper start this scene, so in i am not sure the other thread on this is correct. It might mean a scout trooper, as they are the ones that fight with the ewoks.

Answer (score 0):

There is another question thread on this site that has a more complete listing of which character unlocks which scene.

[Which characters unlock each scene?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142297/which-characters-unlock-each-scene)

Answer (score -1):

Luke unlocks the imperial communications level scene. Thought it was leia I used but when I tried it again I found I was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

For wattos wares its jar jar that needs to be delivered, he chases a pit droid. Same as Mon Espa cafe. Always breaking things.
Also on the Imperial Museum its one of them furry things (ewok?) They spray paint the room and dip out.