# Which characters in Tiny Death Star can be unlocked without paying in Imperial Bux?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Which characters in Tiny Death Star can be unlocked without paying in Imperial Bux?

Comment: I am almost positive all characters unlock through progression...

Comment: Probably true, but I'm wondering if anyone has unlocked anyone else by progression.  It seems random, but I'm especially curious if people have found an association with specific levels or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These seem to unlock in a prescribed order:

Bounty Hunters: Boba Fett, IG-88, Dengar, Greedo, 4-LOM

Droids: C-3PO, FX-7, R5-D4, Pit Droid, Interrogation Droid, (1? still locked)

Men of the Rebellion: Lando, General Lando,  Han Solo, New Hope Luke, (5? still locked)

Ladies of the Rebellion: Bespin Leia, Leia Organa(Rebel), Hoth Leia, Endor Leia, Slave Leia

Rebel Heroes: All unlocked.

Rebel Aliens: Bothan, Ewok, Gungan, Mon Calamari, KelDor, Sullustan (2? still locked)

Outer Rim: Chiss, Gand, Geonosian, Jawa, Toydarian, Ugnaught, Zabrak (4? still locked)

Troops: All unlocked

Rebel Forces: All unlocked

The Force: Emperor Palpatine, Obi Wan Kenobi, Jedi Luke (2? still locked)

Cantina Crew: Aqualish, Arcona, Chadra-fan, Rodian, Snivvian, Devaronian, Duros, Kubaz (3? still locked)

Hutt's Henchmen: Gran, Twi'lek, Weequay, Gamorean, Lando Calrissian (Skiff)

Limited Edition: Boba Fett (Holiday Special), 3? Locked

I know you can click on the ?s and see who they are, I just didn't feel like typing all of them out here.

Answer (score 4):

All the events are random generated:

- new species
- unlocking a character
- finding a character on a certain level
- unlocking scenes
- etc.

So you can unlock any character within the game, and any scene / level / race by random chance.

Comment: I agree that it seems this way. But, is there any source for the info?

Comment: I don't think that there is any official info but through playing is very easy to see that it happens this way.

Comment: Well, I'm cataloging it up top. And, if they all unlock I'll give you credit for the answer.

Comment: It would take a little while since random means that you can bump into the same scene/character multiple times before getting to a new one. But take your time, we do want precise answers.

Comment: Exactly!  Wasn't meant as a knock at you!

Comment: Interestingly, I was looking at a friend's TDS, and he is at about half the progress I am.  The progression may not be so random after all.  He has no characters that I do not.  And, they seem to be filling in a similar order to mine.  While the timing of the appearances may be random, the progression very well may not.

Comment: @DavidM are the generated levels the same as yours?

Comment: I didn't think to look. I'll have to check that out.

Comment: Having levels generated in a different order would indicate that the levels are generated randomly. I remember that on my playthrough i got `mos espa cafe`, `wattos's wares`, `workout center` (excluding the residential levels).

Comment: I had the same levels generated in the same order. But, you also can choose what type of levels you will build. So, I think they unlock in order according to type.

Comment: Then it might be very possible that only imperial levels get randomly generated as it has been previously reported on other questions. I'll update my answer accordingly when I get more proof and evidences. But this would require more than one complete playthrough to see the outcomes in order.

Answer (score 1):

Aqualish also unlock automatically.

Based on your list, which is identical to mine except in that regard, I'm guessing that they unlock on a schedule. It may not be in the same order.

I suspect that they unlock in threes: three new characters, three new races, usually in a relatively sport span of time, and then a long gap before the next unlock.

Interestingly, although Jawa and Duros have been unlocked, I've never had a bitizen of either race appear in the elevator except as part of a ? event.

UPDATE: Since I wrote that, KelDor (rebel aliens) and Weequay (Hutt's henchmen) have unlocked. I've also had Twi'lek show up as customers in my stores.

Comment: You must have missed the notification for Twi'lek.

Comment: It is clearly a progression that everyone runs in the same order.  As, I've just unlocked KelDor.

Comment: I didn't miss the Twi'lek notification. They started showing up as customers in my stores about half an hour before the first one appeared in my elevator, and that's when I got the "you have unlocked...!" notification. From that, I'm assuming that you only get the unlock notification when a new species wants a ride in your elevator. As a result, if you see a new species buying something from one of your stores, that species will likely unlock soon.