# Is there a way to know which will be the next bitizen to unlock in TDS?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I'm playing TDS without spending any Bux to unlock any bitizens.  ([See my other question on that subject.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/143685/what-characters-in-tiny-death-star-can-be-unlocked-without-paying-in-imperial-bu))  And, from conferring with other players, it seems clear that the game unlocks in the same progression for everyone (assuming you don't buy bitizens).

Is there a way to know who is going to unlock next?  I thought it might be the one whose price to unlock is the cheapest in bux, but this has proven incorrect.

Comment: OK, it is clearly NOT the least expensive to unlock.

Comment: Rolled back to previous version.  My question is specifically whether or not there is an indicator which one is next, NOT the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of update 1.3, you can now tell who will be next to unlock by looking in the store or the album.

The price of the next bitizen to unlock will drop to 1 Bux in both places.  If the next to unlock has an associated ? character, then you will see them in the store.  And, the order they appear from the top is the order of unlocking.

This appears to have fixed a bug present in previous versions where this was not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, there is no way of knowing which Bitizen will unlock next.

The game does not offer indicators as it does with Levels.