# Which characters unlock each scene?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

No matter where I look, I haven't seen almost any indications of which characters unlock which scenes.

Put plainly: Which character/level combinations unlock a scene?

Comment: Hi @Alex, welcome to Arqade.  I think I see where you are coming from, but your question would be best reworded, highlighting the specific information you are seeking.  For more info on asking a good question, you can check out [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  I'd suggest rephrasing to something like "What are the conditions for acquiring all unlockable scenes".  Also - the back half of your question is probably more of an answer.

Comment: Good job on the edit.  It looks great now.

Comment: with the new update you can deliver any bitzen with a '?' to any floor you like making it easier to unlock scenes.

Comment: Nothing for Akbar, then? Perhaps a trap?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Food Levels**

- The Cantina -> Han Solo **or** Greedo
- Mos Espa Cafe (the first scene) -> Gungan **or** Gran
- Ithorian Food -> Ithorian
- Scoop of Hoth -> Snow Trooper (Fixed in 1.3.0 update)

**Service Levels**

- Bounty Hunters -> Boba Fett **or** Dengar **or** 4-LOM **or** Gand
- Cloud City Spa -> Han Solo **or** Boba Fett
- Trash Compactor -> Luke **or** Han **or** Chewbacca **or** Leia
- Panna City Medicine -> Boba Fett (Holiday Special)

**Recreational Levels**

- Holochess Hall -> IG-88 **or** Chewbacca
- Holonet Cineplex -> Chadra-fan
- Imperial Museum -> Ewok **or** Snowtrooper **or** Wicket
- Mon Cala Aquarium -> Mon Calamari (not Admiral Akbar)
- Training Remotes -> Obi-wan **or** Luke

**Retail Levels**

- Droid Store -> Greedo **or** R5-D4 **or** Jawa
- Imperial Marches -> R2-Q5 **or** R5-J2 **or** R4-I9 (Service to the Empire Special edition droids)
- Watto's Wares -> Pit Droid **or** Toydarian **or** Watto **or** Gungan

**Residential Levels**

- Dagobah Apts -> Yoda **or** R2-D2
- Tatooine Apts -> C3PO **or** Tusken Raider

**Imperial Levels**

- Blast Door -> Obi-wan Kenobi **or** Darth Vader
- Communications -> Han Solo **or** Luke Skywalker **or** Chewbacca
- Detention Level -> Luke Skywalker **or** Han Solo **or** Leia Organa **or** Chewbacca
- Droid Lab -> Leia Organa
- Extending Bridge -> Luke Skywalker **or** Leia Organa
- Imperial Meeting Room -> Darth Vader
- Interrogation -> Leia Organa **or** Interogation Droid
- Superlaser Ray -> Imperial Gunner
- Tractor Beam -> Obi-wan Kenobi **or** Snowtrooper (new patch)
- Sith Meditation -> Darth Vader

**By Character**

- 4-LOM -> Bounty Hunters
- Bespin Leia -> none
- Boba Fett -> Bounty Hunters, Cloud City Spa
- Boba Fett (Holiday Special) -> Panna City Medicine
- C3PO -> Tatooine Apts
- Chadra-fan -> Holonet Cineplex
- Chewbacca -> Trash Compactor, Communications, Detention Level, Holochess Hall
- Darth Vader - Imperial Meeting Room, Sith Meditation, Interrogation
- Dengar -> Bounty Hunters
- Greedo -> The Cantina, Droid Store
- Gungan -> Mos Espa Cafe, Watto's Wares
- Han Solo -> Communications, Detention Level, Cloud City Spa, Trash Compactor, The Cantina
- IG-88 -> Holochess Hall
- Imperial Gunner -> Superlaser Ray
- Interrogation Droid -> None
- Ithorian -> Ithorian Food
- Jawa -> Droid Store
- Leia Organa (Rebel) -> Interrogation, Extending Bridge, Droid Lab, Detention Level, Trash Compactor
- Luke Skywalker -> Extending Bridge, Detention Level, Communications, Training Remotes, Trash Compactor
- Mon Calamari (not Admiral Ackbar) -> Mon Cala Aquarium
- Obi-wan Kenobi -> Blast Door, Tractor Beam, Training Remotes
- Pit Droid -> Watto's Wares
- R2-D2 -> Droid Lab
- R2-Q5 -> Imperial Marches
- R4-I9 -> Imperial Marches
- R5-D4 -> Droid Store
- R5-J2 -> Imperial Marches
- Scout Trooper -> Imperial Museum
- Snow Trooper -> Tractor Beam, Scoop of Hoth
- TIE Pilot -> Superlaser Ray
- Toydarian -> Watto's Wares
- Tusken Raider -> Tattoine Apts
- Watto -> Watto's Wares
- Wicket (not Ewok) -> Imperial Museum
- Yoda -> Dagobah Apts

Comment: This is the list we have so far. Please feel free to edit it with any new scenes you've discovered!

Comment: Yoda, Vader and Ithorians (species) seem to be unlocked (for free) very late into the game, perhaps this might explain a few of the unknown floors?

Comment: Also, it's a game bug that they call the scene Vader Meditation and the level Sith Meditation. The Emperor does not work there. So, there is only one Sith who can meditate there. Lol.

Comment: It's important to note that when it says Leia, it refers to Leia Organa (Rebel)  I have not successfully triggered any scenes with Bespin Leia.

Comment: Lando and Jawas seem to do nothing; despite post below that mentions Jawas go to the Droid Store.

Comment: Snow troopers also seem useless...

Comment: One of the hardest bitizens to get is the Mon Calamari who is not Akbar.  I had to pay 1 Bux in the bitizen store to get him to unlock even after the species had unlocked.

Comment: Would it be worth it to also list this by character, such as Obi-wan -> Tractor Beam, Blast Door, Training Remotes

Comment: If you want to list by character, go ahead and put it in an answer.  It's not a terrible idea . . .

Comment: PEOPLE PLEASE CONFIRM THAT THE CHARACTER UNLOCKS THE SCENE BEFORE POSTING!  WE'RE NOT LOOKING FOR YOUR GUESSES!!!!  I'M TIRED OF DELETING IG-88 FROM BOUNTY HUNTERS!

Comment: kind of hard to believe the emperor doesn't trigger a scene, or at least that it hasn't been found, if the video icon on his character means he unlocks a scene

Comment: The video icon appears to be on all specific characters from the movies, not related to whether a character can unlock a scene. For example, Imperial Gunner does NOT have the icon, but DOES unlock a scene, and Bespin Leia HAS an icon, but clearly unlocks nothing.

Comment: I decided to try to unlock the Hoth scene with a store snow trooper right after the update, but it didn't work. BUT I did it once again after when the ten-day quest appeared (with a non-store snow trooper) - and the scene was unlocked!

Comment: I also managed to unlock the Bounty Hunters with a Gand. Not sure it is was an anonymous Gand or one in particular.

Comment: Took Luke onto the Extending Bridge level and got nothing.

Comment: Ah, it was ROTJ Luke. Works with ANH Luke.

Answer (score 24):

For your printing and tracking pleasure, as of game version 1.3.2700 (2014 January 18):

[image: Matrix for characters that unlock scenes in Tiny Death Star ver 1.3.2700, updated 2014 Feb 27]

Comment: Latest revision adds Chewbacca as opening Holochess Hall.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the Wikia wiki is kept reasonable up-to-date:

http://tiny-death-star.wikia.com/wiki/Scenes

Comment: The list above is slightly more complete than the wiki (includes information for rare characters like Yoda, Darth Vader, and R2-D2 for example).

Comment: Looks pretty up to date now.

Answer (score -1):

Taken from the [Tiny Death Star Guide](http://quickgamer.net/games/tiny-death-star/scenes-albums/)!
>

- Mos Espa Café – Any Gungan/Jar Jar Binks
- Mon Cala Aquarium - Mon Calamari (not Akbar)
- Bounty Hunters – Any bounty hunter
- Tatooine Apts - C3PO
- The Cantina – Han or Greedo
- Cloud City Spa – Han, Boba Fett
- Communications – Luke Skywalker
- Dagobah Apts - Yoda
- Vader Meditation - Vader
- Detention Level – Luke Skywalker, Han Solo, Princess Leia, Chewbacca
- Droid Lab – Leia
- Droid Store – R5D4, Jawa (verified to work)
- Extending Bridge – Luke Skywalker, Princess Leia
- Holonet Cineplex – Chadra-Fan
- Holochess Hall – Any Droid (I did it with IG-88).
- Imperial Museum – Ewok
- Imperial Meeting Room - Vader
- Interrogation – Princess Leia
- Ithorian Food - Ithorian
- Training Remotes – Luke
- Blast Doors – Obi Wan Kenobi
- Scoop of Hoth
- Superlaser Tunnerl – Imperial Gunner
- Tractor Beam – Obi Wan Kenobi
- Trash Compactor – Leia, Luke, Chewie
- Watto’s Wares – JarJar Bin
- Panna City Medicines - Boba Fett (Holiday Edition)

The Holiday Update introduces Decorator Droid VIPs which introduce limited-time holiday missions. These missions involve delivering Decorator Droids to levels of the player's choice and decorating the level with red and green rope lights.

- Decorate 20 Levels - unlocks Boba Fett (Holiday Edition)
- Decorate 35 Levels - unlocks Panna City Medicines

Comment: Bah I got excited, this doesn't have anything additional... Sorry!

Comment: If you have made a redundant post, you should consider deleting it.

Comment: -1, Jawa doesn't unlock Droid Store

Answer (score -4):

These levels are the set conditions for unlocking all of the scenes:

1. **Mos Espa Cafe** ~ *Food*
2. **Mon Cala Aquarium** ~ *Recreational*
3. **Bounty Hunters** ~ *Service*
4. **Tatooine Apts** ~ *Residential*
5. **The Catina** ~ *Food*
6. **Cloud City Spa** ~ *Service*
7. **Communications** ~ *Imperial*
8. **Dagobah Apts** ~ *Residential*
9. **Vader Meditation** ~ *Imperial*
10. **Detention Level** ~ *Imperial*
11. **Droid Lab** ~ *Imperial*
12. **Droid Store** ~ *Retail*
13. **Extending Bridge** ~ *Imperial*
14. **Holonet Cineplex** ~ *Recreational*
15. **Holochess Hall** ~ *Recreational*
16. **Imperial Museum** ~ *Recreational*
17. **Imperial Meeting Room** ~ *Imperial*
18. **Interrogation** ~ *Imperial*
19. **Ithorian Food** ~ *Food*
20. **Training Remotes** ~ *Recreational*
21. **Blast Doors** ~ *Imperial*
22. **Scoop of Hoth** ~ *Food*
23. **Superlaser Tunnel** ~ *Imperial*
24. **Tractor Beam** ~ *Imperial*
25. **Trash Compactor** ~ *Service*
26. **Watto's Wares** ~ *Retail*

I assume you don't get characters (bitizens with ? sign) unless you have the scene room for them.

After getting all of the levels, patience is the key to receiving the right bitizens desiring the levels for unlocking all of the scenes.

Good luck :)

Comment: You are missing a key component of what he's asking, which is what character goes to which level.

Comment: @Doozer Blake 
If you clearly read the question it asks 'what conditions you must have for unlocking all of the scenes'. The only conditions we have the ability to change are the levels, which I named.
In the description it DOES include asking what characters are used, but it's not the 'key component' because it is not the main question. Also, I cannot add them if I do not know who they are (yet).

I can give what I am aware of, and I see no fault in that.

Comment: I see your point, but the main question being asked was actually a rewording of my original question. I can see the list of locked scenes and the levels they would be in, I really am only interested in which characters need to be sent there. You can unlock characters randomly, and I don't think that has anything to do with which levels you've built, but you can also pay Imperial Bux to unlock specific characters (or levels).

Comment: And I'd question the assumption that you only get ? characters if you have the matching level.