# Which ? characters do NOT seem to unlock any scenes in TDS?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

There seem to be several ? bitizens that DO NOT unlock any scenes.  I want to put together a list of them so people will stop cluttering up [Which character unlock each scene?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142297/which-characters-unlock-each-scene) with them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which characters unlock each scene?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142297/which-characters-unlock-each-scene)

Comment: It is the opposite question of Which characters unlock each scene as is acknowledged above.  Related but not duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characters that DO NOT seem to unlock any scenes:

- **Lando** - Any version
- **Leia** - Bespin, Hoth
- **FX-7**
- **Admiral Akbar**
- **Bothan**
- **KelDor**
- **Sullustan**
- **Chiss**
- **Geonosian**
- **Jawa**
- **Ugnaught**
- **Zabrak**
- **All Troops** - except Tie Pilot, Imperial Gunner, Bike Trooper, Snowtrooper
- **All Rebel Forces**
- **Emperor Palpatine**
- **Cantina Crew** - except Ithorian
- **Hutt's Henchmen**

Comment: 4-LOM unlocks Bounty Hunters...

Answer (score -1):

There is now a movie scene icon in your album, when you open a character's profile -- if they are associated with unlocking a scene. The only exception I have found is Emperor Palpatine. I've taken him to all 82 levels, or so I thought, and nada. Jawa, FX7, and Lando do open scenes.

Comment: The movie scene icon does not indicate that they open a scene. This is proven by the fact that the Imperial Gunner who opens the Superlaser Ray does NOT have an icon. And, which scenes do those other characters open?  No one else has found any before, if you know, please share. If it's based upon the presence of the icon, it's wrong.   The icon actually shows that the character is a "personality" and not a species.