# Why don't some of my "?" characters stop where I direct them to?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

When "?" characters appear, I would always direct them to my topmost floor (58 as of now) for the maximum income. On a few occasions though, I've noticed that some of them were always forced to step out on the 40th or 40+ floor. Initially, I thought this was due to my not putting my finger properly on the "up" button to propel the elevator to continue moving upwards.

Sometimes when the lift "jams" this way, I would quickly put my finger on the "down" button for a couple of floors before pushing the "up" button again and this usually solves my problem.
But just now, when I tried to move down, the lift wouldn't budge. It wouldn't move any higher as well, and my bitizen was forced to exit and walk the rest of the way up instead of reaching his home comfortably.

Does anyone else experience this elevator failure? Is this a bug?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which characters unlock each scene?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142297/which-characters-unlock-each-scene)

Comment: That question does not appear to be a duplicate.

Comment: Agreed.  Most definitely NOT duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the game has some tiny lag moment and the game doesn't detect your finger anymore therefore "deciding" to stop at that level. You only need a few miliseconds to stop the elevator and the character will step out right away. Perhaps this explains your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first report I've seen of this bug.  I would do several things to diagnose the problem.  First, check to be certain that your touch screen is working in that area.  Try other applications and make sure the sensitivity is working.  This has been known to happen on various touch screens in highly used areas.  (e.g. iPhone on the unlock swipe)  I don't think it's the problem, but it would be a shame to troubleshoot the game and find out it's a hardware issue.

If that is not the issue, I would attempt a reinstall of the game.  Depending upon which operating system you are using, this might or might not result in losing your status in the game.  Under the help tab, there is now an individual code for your game.  I recommend recording this number, and emailing support@disneymobile.com before you delete the game and reinstall.

It is my understanding that they have a way to restore your progress via their servers using this ID.  But, to be safe, I would confirm that prior to making any action.

Comment: Well, I guess I can learn to live with this minor inconvenience rather than risking my entire progress in TDS. Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: I would still email the customer support. They might be able to talk you through a reinstall.

Comment: I have successfully restored a game save on Android (and transferred from one phone to a new one).