# Does the Snowtrooper actually unlock Scoop of Hoth?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Today I received a notification from Tiny Death Star.

[image: TDS]

Now, this came as a surprise because we've all tried to get the Snowtrooper to unlock Scoop of Hoth in the past, but without success.

In fact, after receiving this message, I attempted to use the Snowtrooper ? bitizen again, and again to no avail.

I have seen a still shot somewhere of the scene unlock, but no one seems to have been able to trigger it that I know of.

I'm wondering if anyone has done it in the past, but somehow the recent update broke the unlock function on this scene?

There is a related question here: [Which characters unlock each scene?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142297/which-characters-unlock-each-scene)

Comment: Before people flag this as a duplicate, I have posted this separately due to the strange behavior of this particular scene.  It is certainly a related question, but it is not unlocking with the ? bitizen recommended by the game itself!

Comment: I think this is a bug yet to be fixed. Hopefully, the devs would straighten this out in the next update. It's highly unlikely that a whole community of internet users have not found a way to unlock the scene if it's not buggy.

Comment: I agree with you. I was just curious to see if *anyone* was successful on an older build or something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which characters unlock each scene?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142297/which-characters-unlock-each-scene)

Comment: @kotekzot - I've marked this specifically as being different because I believe it represents a broken functionality. My question is NOT does it unlock the scene, but rather is it broken?

Comment: @DavidM if it's broken then it doesn't unlock the scene, if it does unlock the scene then it is not broken.

Comment: @kotekzot of course that is true. But, I'm trying to gather information about whether or not this has EVER worked for anyone. I wish to submit a tech support ticket to Disney and I'm gathering as much info as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the 1.3.0 update, the Snowtrooper now unlocks the Scoop of Hoth cutscene.

[image: screenshot]